# Writing Nukleotide motifs

Tags: spacing, color, letterspacing

Is there a way to write nukleotide motifs like the one in the picture?

There are 4 letters and each is color coded. If there are multiple options for 
one position all options are written underneath each other but the total size stays the same.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: There's a picture, can't I see it?

Comment: So sorry I forgot the picture. I haven't tried anything in LaTeX yet. I am looking through questions to deal with the color coding right now

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this image? Is it a logo, involving DNA nucleotides? At the moment I see only the abbreviations for Thymine, Guanine, Adenine and Cytosine... Is it some particular DNA sequence?

Comment: How it works is as followed. When looking for motif enrichment you have multiple sequences. The first letter with (C/G/A/T) could for example come from 10 sequences in which 4 sequences have a C at this position, 2 sequences a G, 2 a A and 2 a T. 
It is a common way to represent motifs in my case motifs for RNA binding proteins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each stack is made with `\DNA{<component>[<value>]...<component>[<value>]...}{<height>}`.  The `component`s are `\Ad`, `\Gu`, `\Th`, and `\Cy`.  The `value`s are real numbers.  One must be careful, if the `value`s get too high arithmetic overflow occurs.

`\thegap` defines the component of `value` that is dedicated to the white gap between letters.  Setting to `0` will make the letters stack with no gap.

Choosing a value of `-` retains the gap, but without placing the letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\thegap{.5}

\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,xcolor}
\newcommand\Adenine{\textcolor{green}{\sffamily\bfseries A}}
\newcommand\Guanine{\textcolor{orange}{\sffamily\bfseries G}}
\newcommand\Thiamine{\textcolor{red}{\sffamily\bfseries T}}
\newcommand\Cytosine{\textcolor{blue}{\sffamily\bfseries C}}
\def\grow#1[#2]{%
  \ifx-#2\else\stretchto{$#1$}{\dimexpr#2pt-\thegap pt\relax}\fi%
}
\newcommand\Ad{\grow\Adenine}
\newcommand\Gu{\grow\Guanine}
\newcommand\Th{\grow\Thiamine}
\newcommand\Cy{\grow\Cytosine}
\newcommand\DNA[2]{\setstackgap{S}{\thegap pt}\setstackEOL{ }\stretchto{\Shortstack{#1}}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\DNA{\Cy[14] \Gu[4] \Ad[5] \Th[5]}{30pt}%
\DNA{\Cy[17] \Gu[3] \Ad[4] \Th[3]}{30pt}%
\DNA{\Th[17] \Gu[5] \Ad[3] \Cy[-]}{30pt}%
\DNA{\Ad[120] \Gu[40] \Th[4] \Cy[3]}{30pt}%
\DNA{\Th[70] \Gu[20] \Cy[20] \Ad[20]}{30pt}%
\DNA{\Ad[90] \Gu[20] \Cy[20] \Th[5]}{30pt}%
\end{document}
```

[image]